# Why does my android app still vibrate even though I've turned off the Vibrate on Touch in setting?

Tags: android, android-vibration

Just testing the vibrations permissions in my android app. 
I've got it doing some haptic feedbacks which is nice.

The odd thing is when I turn the phones *Vibrate on Touch* setting off, the home and back buttons stop vibrating but my app still allows it. why is that?

Comment: If you are playing audio in your app, you have to have `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`
in place so your app has the same volume as the system volume, otherwise your app will operate on its own independent volume setting. Perhaps similar situation here.

Comment: Maybe try `setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);` API suggests it allows app to mirror user settings for vibration/silent mode etc.

Comment: right, i just tried looking into your suggestion and by default the ringer mode is set to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to turn off "Auto" Haptic Feedback in the settings.